# AspnetCore EF6 Relationships

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a (EF6) DbContext for accessing existing MYSQL database.
I have used this context in AspNet project and so far had no problems with class mappings. Currently am in process in moving the project to asp net core and for some strange reason i am not able to use the context with AspNetCore as i constantly getting mapping exceptions e.g

Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types

Of course i checked the mappings and they are correct, same mapping works in other application types with same EF version.

Is there any chance i missing some configuration and thus explain context behavior?

Comment: Actually i can see that EF queries try to select with property names instead of actual column name e.g CustomerId where it should been customer_id. I use attribute mapping and no fluent api.

Comment: OK the problem it seems that EF completely ignores any attribute on entities and uses Fluent Api instead. Can somebody explain this ?